# Add loading message partial view jQuery MVC3

Tags: jquery, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, partial-views

I have a pretty simple registration wizard form.  This is an MVC3\Razor project written in VB.

My last step displays a partial view with the user's entered details. Since the partial can take a split second to load, the form looks odd until it does - a blank form with a couple of buttons.

Is there a clean, proper way to display a little loading image/message while the partial is loading so it's obvious to the user he/she needs to hold on a second?

My code for the register view:

```
    $(function () {

    $(".wizardstep:first").fadeIn(); // show first step

    // attach back button handler
    // hide on first step
    $("#register-backstep").hide().click(function () {
        var $step = $(".wizardstep:visible"); // get current step
        if ($step.prev().hasClass("wizardstep")) { // is there any previous step?
            $step.hide().prev().fadeIn();  // show it and hide current step

            // disable backstep button?
            if (!$step.prev().prev().hasClass("wizardstep")) {
                $("#register-backstep").hide();
            }
        }
    });


    // attach next button handler       
    $("#register-nextstep").click(function () {

        var $step = $(".wizardstep:visible"); // get current step

        var validator = $("form").validate(); // obtain validator
        var anyError = false;
        $step.find("input").each(function () {
            if (!validator.element(this)) { // validate every input element inside this step
                anyError = true;
            }

        });

        if (anyError)
            return false; // exit if any error found

        if ($step.next().hasClass("confirm")) { // is it the confirmation div?
            // post to the controller and show confirmation partial view asynchronously
            $.post("ConfirmRegister", $("form").serialize(), function (r) {
                // inject response in confirmation step
                $(".wizardstep.confirm").html(r);
            });

        }

        if ($step.next().hasClass("wizardstep")) { // is there a next step?
            $step.hide().next().fadeIn();  // show it and hide the current step
            $("#register-backstep").show();   // recall to show back button
        }

        else { // this is last step, submit form
            $("form").submit();
        }


    });

});

<div class="uni-form">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="wizardstep">
            <h2>Step 1: Your Username</h2>
            <p class="wizardnote">Please choose a username you will use to login to >your account.</p>                
        </div>
        <div class="wizardstep">
            <h2>Step 2: Your Email Address</h2>
            <p class="wizardnote"></p>                
        </div>
        <div class="wizardstep">
            <h2>Step 3: Choose a Password</h2>
            <p class="wizardnote"></p>                
        </div>
        <div class="wizardstep confirm"></div>
        <div class="buttoncontainer">
            <input type="button" value="&larr;Back" id="register-backstep" />
            <input type="button" value="Next Step" id="register-nextstep" />
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

The partial view for now is just a dummy display of the model elements.

Answer (score 1):

Use a fixed position div that is the height/width of the containing div (uni-form) and probably jack it's z-index up so it is definitely on top of the form when visible.

```
var h= $(.uni-form).height();
var w= $(.uni-form).width();
```

Position the loading icon wherever appropriate.

You can use CSS to set the opacity of the overlaying (loading) div so they can see the form behind it and that it's on it's way. When the form is done loading, fade the overlaying div out.

Hopefully that helps. I recommend this route if you are trying to keep the user from poking around while everything loads.

Comment: i think the blockui plugin is a cheap, but effective way out. thank you for the response -- also solid.